# Covert Image automatically to bitmap after getting the image from local phone storage

Tags: java, android

I getting images from my user's local storage but the images are taking a longer time to load in some phones, So I would like them to reduce to a smaller size by converting them to bitmap format.

Below is the code that fetches images :

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_CODE && data!=null){
        imageUri = data.getData();
        addImagePost.setImageURI(imageUri);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the received image path uri to bitmap like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
addImagePost.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```